# Slide-down animation

Tags: android, animation, xamarin.android

I am trying to animate a `TextView` sliding down from behind an `ImageView`. I've got the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/image_background"
    android:visibility="invisible" 
    android:layout_below="@id/image"
    />
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/image_background"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/question"
  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout` to get the `description TextView` to appear behind the `ImageView` (z-index-wise).

Note that the `TextView` can vary in the length of the text, and when filled in it is frequently longer than the image. There is also other views above and below that `RelativeLayout`.

I've tried with this animation

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <translate android:fromYDelta="-100%p" android:toYDelta="0"
      android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
  <scale android:fromYScale="0.0" android:toYScale="1.0"
      android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
</set>
```

...and using

```
descriptionView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
Animation a = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.push_down);
descriptionView.StartAnimation(a);
```

However, this is choppy, and does not begin where I thought it would begin, nore does the scaling work. I've read about layout animations, and that the animation can be triggered automatically when the visibility changes, but I don't know how.

How do I get the animation to work, and is there an easier solution?

Comment: Animations in general are not very smooth on Android, if you are targeting a version on Android 3.0+ you can enable Hardware Acceleration http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-30-hardware-acceleration.html

Comment: Where to you expect the animation to begin? You are setting the Y delta to -100%p which would start the animation up descriptionView.Height amount of pixels from it's starting location.